# Set ScaffoldColumn(false) in runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyModel)` and I would like to add or set the Id property in my model as a hidden field. This can be done i code by using the `ScaffoldColumnAttribute` but I would like to do this at runtime. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to change it at runtime? Can't you set it to false in your model's code?

Comment: @yannick-blondeau yes I can, I guess that is a better solution but I was just curious

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is what you want, you can use `@Html.HiddenFor(s=>s....)`

Comment: Yes, of course but that does not remove the property when I use EditorFor

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to achieve is to hide the `ID` field of the `MyModel` entity when calling `EditorFor(m => m.MyModel)`, then you can use an `EditorTemplate`.

In your `Views/Shared` folder, create a new folder called `EditorTemplates`. In that folder create a new view called `MyModel.cshtml` which content will be something like this:

```
@model ***.MyModel

@if (Model != null) {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
}

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Property1);
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Property1);
```

The test on the existence of the model is here to handle the `Create` view.

And finally, to handle the `DisplayFor` case you will have to add a template for this also, named `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MyModel.cshtml`

Comment: thanks for trying to help but I know there is other ways to create editors, hidden and so on. What my question is all about is if I _must_ use `Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyModel)` is it possible to, in runtime modify a single property in my model so it's not visible in the form? I don't think this is a good idea anymore but I'm just curious if it's possible